# Cant cut using Boxcutter

Tags: modeling

I just bought Boxscatter + HardOps, and immediately there was a problem: I can't create a red box inside the cube. I run along the edge with the LMB clamped down, and all that happens is the "Drawing" and "Canceled" messages in the corner. At the same time, the addon itself works: if you do not select the cube, then Boxcutter perfectly creates parallelepipeds and cylinders around the scene. What am I doing wrong? Of course, Blender version is the newest. Boxcutter is 717_1 Claymore
[image: Blender screenshot]

Comment: If you believe this is a bug, you could [contact the developer](https://boxcutter-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#contact-email).

Answer (score 3):

thanks to recent API changes raycasted was affected. This can be rectified by having a version of Blender 2.83.7, 2.90.1 or 2.91.0 via Buildbot.
https://youtu.be/BIlAj-y-BXk

When it comes up updating [HardOps / Boxcutter](https://hardops-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#how-do-i-update-hard-ops-boxcutter)

When it [comes to Blender itself](https://www.blender.org/download/)

As time goes on with multiple versions they receive updates even though they are of different branches.
2.83 is an LTS which recently received a .7 update.

2.90 was previously experiencing stability issues which received a hotfix of .1

2.91.0 is a future version not yet release but we support it as well since all three have the same api recent changes.

In short update blender to the latest.

While 2.90 is correct the month may not be.

Get a current 2.90.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem related to Blender but BoxCutter. You should contact the developer instead. But probably is the version not matching your Blender version